# git clone couldn't resolve fqdn thus cloning fails

Tags: git

The issue is on windows -  i dont know if that is ok on linux or not

The hosts file contains:
1.2.3.4 example_host

example_host answers for ping, so it's available
also git clone https://1.2.3.4/mygroup1/myrepo1.git can clone the repo

Why is not the below working:
git clone https://example_host/mygroup1/myrepo1.git

the error is :
Cloning into 'myrepo1'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://example_host/mygroup1/myrepo1.git/': Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to unset your proxy variables:

1. List them `env|grep -i proxy`
2. Unset them i.e in my case `unset  HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY http_proxy https_proxy`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT

Means it resolve correctly, but you are using a proxy, which doesn't now that host. Try to disable your local proxy or to put the `example_host` IP in the proxy's exception list.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the proxy is not handled by me. example_host is put to hosts file by a script which knows the actual IP address of the git repo (dynamic IP used), so that's why i would like to use example_host when im working with git... this would simplify the work... any other workaround?

Comment: another possible solution would be to write a bash script which everytime when I want to push/fetch reads the actual IP, changes the remote url for push and fetch and finally can push/fetch the repo.  but maybe there is a better solution